# Exchange 2007 - Unable to Start Information Store - Error IMAIL_E_CODE_PAGE_CONVERSION

Tags: windows, exchange-2007, small-business

We're currently having an issue with an Exchange server (running 2007) where we cannot start the Information Store server.

No new updates or programs have been installed.

Currently the server is running Exchange 2007 on Windows Small Business Server 2011 Standard (SP1).

The errors we're encountering are:

Log Name:      Application

Source:        MSExchangeIS

Date:          26/09/2014 11:39:31 AM

Event ID:      1180

Task Category: Content Engine

Level:         Error

Keywords:      Classic

User:          N/A

Computer:      bbb.aaa.local

Description:
Error 0x80040c07 initializing the Microsoft Exchange Server Internet Conversion Library. 
Event Xml:

  
    
    1180
    2
    11
    0x80000000000000
    
    887049
    Application
    bbb.aaa.local
    
  
  
    0x80040c07

And

Log Name:      Application

Source:        MSExchangeIS

Date:          26/09/2014 11:39:31 AM

Event ID:      5000

Task Category: General

Level:         Error

Keywords:      Classic

User:          N/A

Computer:      bbb.aaa.local

Description:
Unable to initialize the Microsoft Exchange Information Store service.   - Error 0x80040c07. 
Event Xml:

  
    
    5000
    2
    6
    0x80000000000000
    
    887050
    Application
    bbb.aaa.local
    
  
  
    
    
    0x80040c07

Researching the errors suggests we need to install a code pack, but I can only find details on how to do this in older versions of the server OS. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. The file c_20127.nls was missing from C:\Windows\System32.